# EWS C# Loop over Group Inbox email

Tags: exchangewebservices, inbox

I have seen a couple of incomplete answers on here.  I am trying to loop over the emails in an inbox of a shared mail group and see properties like 'Sender'.

I understand that certain classes used would simply loop through my own default email inbox and not that of the group inbox specified.

Would appreciate some guidance or working example.

Comment: You need to add the code your currently using, i would also suggest you try using the EWSEditor first to see if you can open that group mailbox in question. The code in question should be no different then enumerating through any delegates Mailbox folders. That said the REST API is a better API to use for Groups

Comment: Are you saying that if I impersonate or be delegated a user who is member of the group, I can then loop over just that group's inbox emails?

Comment: Hi,I believe I have solved this challenge now.  Thanks for your help.